# How to remove the line of Ant design's "Step component"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to know how to erase the line of Steps component in Ant design.
Does anyone know the method?
[image: Ant-design official description]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove by modifying the `css` classes of steps component

```
.ant-steps-item > .ant-steps-item-container > .ant-steps-item-content > .ant-steps-item-title::after {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```